# Authorize only controller allows anonymous access in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have setup identity in a .net core web app, and marked a certain controller as authorize like this..

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Partner")]
public class ClaimsController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Partner")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var authenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        //authenticated is false - but this view still loads?!
        return View();          
    }
}
```

So only users in the partner role should have access.. However someone not logged in at all can load and view the Index view on the claims controller.. I could check if someone is logged in and check the role user explicitly with the user manager but surely these attributes should do something?

Is there something extra I need in startup.cs in core 3? This is my startup.cs file..

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connstring = _config.GetConnectionString("HP_RBS_Database");

        //we can create our own role and derive from IdentityRole
        services.AddIdentity<UserLogin, IdentityRole>(x =>
        {
            x.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            //set password rules in here..
        })  //specify where we store identity data
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<HP_RBS_Context>();

        services.AddMvc();          
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddDbContext<HP_RBS_Context>(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServer(connstring);
            });

        services.AddTransient<HPPartnerPortalSeeder>();
        services.AddScoped<IHP_RBS_Repository, HP_RBS_Repository>();
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(x =>
        {
            x.MapControllerRoute("Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls to `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` must be placed between `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(x =>
{
    x.MapControllerRoute("Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

When these calls are placed *before* `UseRouting`, the `UseAuthorization` call is somewhat of a no-op. It checks to see whether an endpoint has been selected, but this hasn't happened yet. The selection process is performed courtesy of the `UseRouting` call that runs next, which is too late.

Unfortunately, this means that the MVC endpoint runs as though authorisation succeeded, eventhough it wasn't performed at all. This is a known issue in the 3.0.0 release of ASP.NET Core, which has been fixed in the 3.0.1 release.

Comment: How exactly has this been fixed? This is a major thing you can easily look over

Comment: @Marcel The endpoint will no longer run. It'll throw an exception instead.